Neccesary conditions so that $\ker(A^2)= \ker(A) \cap \text{Im} (A)$
Consider a finite dimensional vector space $V$, and an endomorphism $A: V\to V$ , I am trying to figure out what are the neccesary conditions so that $\ker(A^2)= \ker(A) \cap \text{Im} (A)$ holds. A set of sufficient conditions I found is if $ \ker(A) = \text{Im} (A)$.
Another neccesary condition I noticed is that $\ker (A) \neq V$ , else the statement will include the zero matrix , making it false.
Help?

What is $F$ in $\ker(F)$?

Note that $\ker(A)\subseteq\ker(A^2)$ always holds. If you also have $\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)\cap\mathrm{Im}(A) \subseteq \ker(A)$, then you must have $\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)$.

$\def\ker{\mathop{\rm ker}}$You should note that certainly $\ker(A^2)\supseteq \ker(A)$, since if $Av=0$ then certainly $A(Av)=0$. On the other hand you're asking for $\ker(A^2)$ to be a subset of $\ker(A)$. This forces a lot.

Use ^2 for square. This is a built in functionality in LaTeX. You don't need to grab a special character for it.

$\ker(A) = \operatorname{img}(A)$ is not sufficient. For example, $A = (x,y) \mapsto (y,0)$ satisfies $\ker(A) = \operatorname{img}(A)$ but does not satisfy $\ker(A)^2 = \ker(A) \cap \operatorname{img}(A)$.

Note that $\ker(A)\subseteq\ker(A^2)$ always holds. If you also have $\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)\cap\mathrm{Im}(A) \subseteq \ker(A)$, then you must have $\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)$.
So you are asking for $\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)\cap\mathrm{Im}(A) = \ker(A^2)\cap\mathrm{Im}(A)$. So this requires $\ker(A)\subseteq\mathrm{Im}(A)$.
This is also sufficient.
Theorem. Let $A\colon V\to V$ be an operator on a vector space $V$. Then $\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)\cap\mathrm{Im}(A)$ if and only if $\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)$ and $\ker(A)\subseteq\mathrm{Im}(A)$.
Proof. If the conditions holds, then $\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)=\ker(A)\cap\mathrm{Im}(A)$. Conversely, assume that $$\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)\cap\mathrm{Im}(A)\tag{$*$}.$$
Since $\ker(A)\subseteq\ker(A^2)$, and $(*)$ requires $\ker(A^2)\subseteq\ker(A)$, it follows that $\ker(A)=\ker(A^2)$; then $(*)$ becomes $\ker(A^2)=\ker(A) = \ker(A)\cap\mathrm{Im}(A)$, which implies that $\ker(A)\subseteq\mathrm{Im}(A)$, as required. $\Box$
Added. $\ker(A)=\ker(A^2)$ means that if $x\in\mathrm{Im}(A)\cap\ker(A)$, then $x=\mathbf{0}$, since $x=Ay$, $\mathbf{0}=Ax = A^2y$, so $y\in\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)$, hence $x=Ay=\mathbf{0}$. Thus, $\mathrm{Im}(A)\cap\ker(A)=\{\mathbf{0}\}$
Then $\ker(A)\subseteq\mathrm{Im}(A)$ gives $\ker(A)=\ker(A^2) = \ker(A)\cap\mathrm{Im}(A) = \{\mathbf{0}\}$, so $A$ is one-to-one.
In the finite dimensional case, this gives $A$ invertible and $V=\ker(A)\oplus\mathrm{Im}(A)$, as noted by user8675309.
In the infinite dimensional case it just gives $A$ is one-to-one. E.g., the right shift operator on the space of infinite dimensional sequences, or the operator $T(p(x)) = xp(x)$ on the vector space of polynomials.
So:
Theorem. Let $A\colon V\to V$ be an operator on a vector space $V$. Then $\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)\cap\mathrm{Im}(A)$ if and only if $\ker(A)=\{\mathbf{0}\}$; i.e., $A$ is one-to-one.
Proof. As above, $\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)\cap\mathrm{Im}(A)$ gives $\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)$ and $\ker(A)\subseteq\mathrm{Im}(A)$; the first gives $\ker(A)\cap\mathrm{Im}(A)=\{\mathbf{0}\}$, which yields that $A$ is one-to-one. Conversely, if $A$ is one-to-one, then both $\ker(A^2)$ and $\ker(A)\cap\mathrm{Im}(A)$ equal $\{\mathbf{0}\}$.

This feels incomplete.  $\ker (A^2)=\ker A \implies V = \ker A \oplus \text{Im } A$  $\implies \ker A = \ker A \cap \text{ Im }(A) = \big{\mathbf 0\big}$, i.e. $A$ is invertible

@user8675309 Right you are, though the direct sum equality only holds in the finite dimensional case.
